# How the get derived class type from base class

Tags: c#, hierarchy

I'm trying to refactor a method which I use in a lot of clases. It's simpler to explain it by an example.

I have this class:

```
    public class TipoPuntoClaveConst
    {
        public const int Insercion = 1;
        public const int DetectorDePaso = 2;
        public const int Sincronizador = 3;
        public const int Extraccion = 4;

        public static string GetDescripcion(int IdxTipo)
        {
            var property = typeof(TipoPuntoClaveConst)
                .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
                .Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly && (int)fi.GetRawConstantValue() == IdxTipo)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (property == null) return string.Empty;
            var name = property.Name;
            return ResourceHelper.GetTraduccion(ResourceHelper.FICHERO.General, name);
        }
    }
```

In the project, I also have a ResourceFile for localization. The `GetDescription` method, returns the localized text using the correct property name given a value. You can see an example of use:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <select id="cbTipo">
            <option value="@TipoPuntoClaveConst.Insercion">@TipoPuntoClaveConst.GetDescripcion(TipoPuntoClaveConst.Insercion)</option>
            ...
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, that I have to copy-paste that method in all of my const classes. I'm trying to implement this method in a base class, something like:

```
public class TipoPuntoClaveConst : ConstMaster {...}

public class ConstMaster {
    public static string GetDescripcion(int IdxTipo)
    {
        var property = typeof(TipoPuntoClaveConst)
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
            .Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly && (int)fi.GetRawConstantValue() == IdxTipo)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (property == null) return string.Empty;
        var name = property.Name;
        return ResourceHelper.GetTraduccion(ResourceHelper.FICHERO.General, name);
    }
}
```

But I cannot figure out, how to replace `var property = typeof(TipoPuntoClaveConst)`, for something more general, like  `var property = typeof(¿this?)`

Comment: Why dont you `Type myType = this.GetType()` ?

Comment: Because `GetDescripcion` is a static method

Comment: If you do not declare the method static and in base class you `this.GetType()` inside a method, when instantiating a child/inherited class and calling that method in the child instance you would get the correct type (the child/inherited one).

Comment: @bradbury9 I know, but i don't want to remove the `static` If you take a look to example of us I am not declaring an object to call the method, so, by removing it I will have to review all my code to correct it for all of my const classes.

Comment: You want it static but dont want to instance, ok, just edited my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your problem is with types and inheritance, I am explaining you the alternatives you do have but avoiding the reflection part.

1. Non static method getting the type using `this.GetType()`
2. Static method, providing an instance of the class as an function
   parameter.
3. Static generic method, not providing and instance.

I would go the non-static because of simplicity, but it depends on the usage you want to give it. From your comments on your question, you could take advantage of generics.

```
namespace InheritanceTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Base: {new BaseClass().CheckType()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Child: {new ChildClass().CheckType()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Static in base with child argument: {BaseClass.CheckType(new ChildClass())}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Static generic in base:{BaseClass.CheckType<ChildClass>()}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class BaseClass
    {
        public string CheckType()
        {
            return this.GetType().ToString();
        }

        public static string CheckType(BaseClass instance)
        {
            return instance.GetType().ToString();
        }

        public static string CheckType<T>() where T: BaseClass
        {
            return typeof(T).ToString();
        }
    }

    public class ChildClass : BaseClass
    {
    }
}
```

The output is the following one

```
Base: InheritanceTest.BaseClass
Child: InheritanceTest.ChildClass
Static in base with child argument: InheritanceTest.ChildClass
Static generic in base: InheritanceTest.ChildClass
```

Comment: Thanks for the enlargement, but I think I won't be able to do what i was thinking. The main problem is to avoid the review of all the uses of this method. `TipoPuntoClaveConst` is only one of the classes but i have a bunch of` xxxConst` classes. all of them with his own `static GetDescripcion` method. All of the solutions you gave me, are good ones, but a medium effort is required to change all uses, either to declare an object before using the method, or to pass an object as an argument. Maybe for the next sprint :)

Answer (score 2):

When you call the `GetDescription` method it will be either the base class object itself or some derived class object. But in base you don't know which dervied class it is. You will need to use `GetType` method to get it's actual type on run-time as **@bradbury9** mentioned in the comments like:

```
public string GetDescripcion(int IdxTipot)
{
    var property = this.GetType()
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
            .Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly && (int)fi.GetRawConstantValue() == IdxTipo)
            .FirstOrDefault();

   if (property == null) return string.Empty;
    var name = property.Name;
    return ResourceHelper.GetTraduccion(ResourceHelper.FICHERO.General, name);
}
```

It's better to keep it as instance method, if you really need it as static then you will need to take the object as parameter input:

```
public static string GetDescripcion(int IdxTipo,TipoPuntoClaveConst objec)
{
    var property = object.GetType()
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
            .Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly && (int)fi.GetRawConstantValue() == IdxTipo)
            .FirstOrDefault();

   if (property == null) return string.Empty;
    var name = property.Name;
    return ResourceHelper.GetTraduccion(ResourceHelper.FICHERO.General, name);
}
```

Comment: `But in base you don't know which dervied class it is` If there is no way to know that, then I simply can't do what I want. Keeping the method in the derived class it's what I want to avoid, because i have to copy-pasy the same code in all classes. But, If move that code to a base clase, implies changing the parameters, i can't assume the modification. Then, I will have to change all my code to update all the calls to that method. Thanks for the help

Comment: Sugested and edit to your answer, your second code snippet needed `TipoPuntoClaveConst object` argument and your first one needed `this.GetType()`

Comment: @bradbury9 thanks, i had edited it at first place, but the changes are lost some how

Comment: Probably mods though I was altering too much, thats why I added the comment